# Determine InnoDB FK Constraints without information_schema

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, information-schema

I'm writing some code to inspect a MySQL database structure, and need information about Foreign Key constraints (on InnoDB tables).

There are two ways I know of to do this:

1. Parse the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE X`
2. Use `INFORMATION_SCEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`

Unfortunately option two requires MySQL 5.1.16 or later, so I can't use it unless/until I can convince our server guy to update, And while I can probably get away with option 1, it feels messy and without writing a full SQL parser I wouldn't feel sure my code would always work with any table.

Is there another way of getting at this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the MySQL 5.0 manual online](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> You can also display the foreign key constraints for a table like
>   this:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'tbl_name';
```

> The foreign key constraints are listed in the **Comment** column of the
>   output.

---

Poster indicates that this doesn't provide `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` information which is an important part of foreign key behavior.

Another option:

Since you control the code involved, is it possible to set up another MySQL instance in the same environment which **is** version 5.1+?  If so, let's call that instance *dummy*.  Run the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on the live database.  Then, on *dummy* run a `DROP TABLE IF EXIST` followed by the output from the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query.

Now you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` on the *dummy* database to get the information.

Comment: Thanks, though that doesn't give me the `ON UPDATE`/`ON DELETE` info.

Comment: @DaedalusFall: Ok.  How about another option...  Updated answer.

Comment: Hah! Nice hack! Sadly I can't launch a mysql instance from my code (php in safe mode), and I think our server guy wouldn't be pleased about me running one constantly. Good stuff tho. I'm thinking I'm just going to have to wait until the upgrade.